# Problem with the characters 'span' in URL (Magento 1.9.1.0)

Tags: url, product-urls

I have encountered a strange but irritating problem in the webshop I am working on. In some URL's from the productpages the word spanband (lashing strap in English) and this causes a  great problem with the layout of the page.

In the source there is the body tag:

```
<body class=" catalog-product-view catalog-product-view product-spanband-5-ton categorypath-accessoires-9-html category-accessoires">
```

Somehow the word span is picked out by the browser as it would be a span tag instead of part of the word spanband. This causes the whole layout to be destroyed. In the inspector in Chrome I can see that the browser uses this bit of CSS from bootstrap-responsive.css

```
[class*="span"] {float: left;min-height: 1px;margin-left: 30px;}
```

Unfortunally I can not remove the word spanband from the URL's. Anybody who has a clue what can be the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty much hit the nail on the head yourself with what is going on. `[class*="span"]` is a CSS selector that will match any element with a class that **contains** the string "span." You know the problem.

As for the solution, I'd be hesitant to remove that CSS, not being familiar with its purpose. However, you can try to override it with your own rule targeting `body.product-spanband-5-ton` directly or `body[class*="spanband"]` generically (if you have more than one product triggering this behavior) at a higher specificity than the trouble causing selector. Try to avoid using `!important` if at all possible to achieve that greater specificity (http://cssspecificity.com/).

Comment: Adam, I'll look into it and thanks for your advise.